# How do you add a jp@gc - Remote Driver Config to a JMeter test using java code

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I am trying to add a RemoteDriverConfig element to an existing JMeter test using java code, and then proceed to run the JMeter test on my existing selenium hub and nodes. I am not trying to write selenium tests in JMeter or anything like that, just using the node to run an API JMeter test. When I create a new “RemoteDriverConfig” object to add to the Jmeter test, I am getting the following failure: "Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException”.

Here is a code snippet (just using chrome for the Capability):

```
import com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.RemoteDriverConfig;

RemoteDriverConfig seleniumHubConfig = new RemoteDriverConfig();
seleniumHubConfig.setCapability(RemoteCapability.CHROME);
seleniumHubConfig.setSeleniumGridUrl(remoteUrl);
testPlanTree.add("remoteDriverConfig", seleniumHubConfig);
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
This is the list of imports

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_components</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jorphan</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-webdriver</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [NoClassDefFoundError JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.

My expectation is that your installation of JMeter [WebDriver Sampler Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) is broken or incomplete as you simply seem to be missing some [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) core libraries in your [CLASSPATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)).

If you are trying to do this from JMeter - I would recommend installing clean JMeter instance (get latest version available at the [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) and add WebDriver support via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) - it will automatically handle dependencies.

Comment: I am using java to run the jmeter test so there isn't anything to re-install. Maven is handling dependencies and I have added the imports to the question. I don't believe the issue is with needing to add more imports, it seems to me that a remote session is expected when I create the RemoteDriverConfig object in java.